# How to handle passport authentication response and show it to the user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm authenticating my **nodeJs** app using passport local strategy. Everything is working fine. But how can I show the user appropriate message that he has entered **invalid login credentials**. My present code is just sending **401 unauthorized error** on screen.

Here is my code

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({
        username : username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        // No user found with that username
        if (!user) {
            return callback(null, false);
        }

        // Make sure the password is correct
        user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            // Password did not match
            if (!isMatch) {
                return callback(null, false);
            }

            // Success
            return callback(null, user);
        });
    });
}));

exports.isLocalAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('local', {
    session : true
});

router.post('/', authController.isLocalAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    //here I want to show the error message to user

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) has clearly described your case under **Custom Callback** section.

You need to add custom callback like this:

```
exports.isLocalAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); } //error exception

        // user will be set to false, if not authenticated
        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json(info); //info contains the error message
        } else {
            // if user authenticated maintain the session
            req.logIn(user, function() {
                // do whatever here on successful login
            })
        }    
    })(req, res, next);
}
```

You don't need to specify the latter callback.

Comment: req,res are undefined here! As per documentation, the only way is we need to call this authenticate function in the route itself.

Comment: the "Custom Callback" section does not exist in the current documentation (maybe they changed the docs); so the question remains: how to customize the response ?